# Looking for ways to determine whether the machine is "overloaded"

Tags: .net, performance, load

I have a setup where tasks are assigned to various agents. My problem is that I would like an agent to report if it is "overloaded".

I understand that the question is very vague, so I am now going to elaborate a bit.

A task usually fetches something from the database, processes the data and then writes it back to the database (either the same or another one). Some tasks may fetch quite a lot of data and some - very few. Most are primarily I/O bound, but some may also include heavy CPU bound computations.

The current agent architecture is such that an agent only has a constant number of concurrent threads dedicated to running the tasks - a thread per task (I know it is bad, but this is a different story). Such a thread is called a **task thread**. Of course, tasks are free to spawn any number of **worker threads** they want. This does not change the number of the **task threads**.

Anyway, when each and every task thread is busy executing some heavy task, then the agent is said to be **Unresponsive**. We recognize this situation pretty easily.

However, there is another scenario. An agent may have vacant task threads. But the volume of work done by the other task threads may be such that the agent may not be able to handle anything, but very light tasks. For example, it may be running low on available RAM to the point that making it execute a moderately complicated task is going to cause excessive swapping resulting in severe crippling of the agent.

A legitimate question is what is a light task? Again, this is a different story. Suppose the task metadata contains such a flag and suppose such tasks are truly light - they fetch no or very little data, they do no heavy computations, demand little memory.

Back to the original question - I need another status, in addition to **Unresponsive** - **Overloaded**. The task assigning logic will only assign light tasks to Overloaded agents.

What are my options here? Right now, the only metric I can think of is the amount of free physical memory (still need to check what .NET API returns this figure).

It could be nice to be able to measure the CPU and Hard Disk load (not the amount of free space!). Other metrics could be the amount of open SQL connections, available thread pool threads.

I am looking for an advice here, maybe people have already encountered and solved a similar problem, their experience is of great interest to me.

We work in .NET 4.52 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think better way is to reverse "assign task to worker" to "worker fetch tasks from common queue" -  take look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html.
The only way to understand worker PC is out of capacity is pooling CPU|MEMORY|IO status via WMI...

Comment: It is the same. If the agent is Overloaded it should not fetch any tasks, except the light ones.

Comment: It's not 100% same. This logic belongs to agent and you doesn't need "assigner|balancer" component. Anyway use WMI to detect CPU|MEMORY|DISK utilization

Comment: btw. Instead of trying to implement such "overload diagnostics logic" first try more simple solution: implement common job queue (or just try Gearman) and try how it behave.

Comment: OK, you have exposed me. We do move away from the current architecture to the one where agents will fetch tasks by themselves from a common queue. This does not change the fact that an Overloaded agent should not fetch anything, but light tasks. So, the need is relevant regardless of the actual architecture. Using WMI is a good idea. I am going to wait a bit to see if there are any other replies.

Comment: How much agents does you have? How did you solve "deploy\update worker logic" problem? "Heavy" jobs - how much "heavy" they are? I believe for CPU-intence jobs you just can limit maximum parallel tasks execution = count of CPU cores. You can also just define some limits for IO and Memory consuming tasks. I think proper limitations is enought....

Comment: The number of agents is dynamic. Right now the largest cluster is 4 agents and one master. But that number is likely to grow. What is the  "deploy\update worker logic" problem? Please, elaborate on IO and Memory limits. I would love to see how to set them per a task. We have one `AppDomain` per agent, by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58463/discussion-between-dimzon-and-mark).